# how to call a java function from a jsp page other than the one within<%%> tags?

Tags: java, jsp

I did a function call (coding shown below) but I still have a compilation error.
I am using this in NetBeans environment.

```
<textarea name="txt" rows="10" cols="85" disabled>
<% 
String str=request.getParameter("rep"); 
blog bg=new blog();
bg.add(str);  
%>
</textarea>
```

The compilation error points to the line where I create an instance of the class blog.
The error is **'cant find class symbol'**.(though I have created my class blog)

Comment: Where's the class defined? Did you import it? `<%@ page import="yourPackage.blog" %>` Or `yourPackage.blog bg = new yourPackage.blog();`

Comment: Although not required, classes start with a capital letter by convention (it helps when others read your code).

Answer (score 0):

Code should be

```
<textarea name="txt" rows="10" cols="85" disabled></textarea>
<% 
String str=request.getParameter("rep"); 
blog bg=new blog();
bg.add(str);  
%>
```